# can we customize the file open buffer size in Julia

Tags: julia, buffer

`open()` sets a memory buffer as defined by `io.h`: `IOS_BUFSIZE` = 32kb (previously 128kb)

Is it possible to change that value (future `open` kwargs?) or adapt it to disk blocksize (often very large in GPFS, etc)?

Comment: Have you considered using mmap?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, it's currently not possible to change this from Julia (short of re-implementing `ios.c:_buf_realloc` in Julia).  It would be pretty easy to add this feature to Julia via a PR.  e.g. add something like the following to `src/support/ios.c`:

```c
int ios_growbuf(ios_t *s, size_t sz)
{
    return _buf_realloc(s, sz) == NULL;
}
```

and then something like the following in `base/iostream.jl`:

```
function sizehint!(s::IOStream, sz::Integer)
    ccall(:ios_growbuf, Cint, (Ptr{Cvoid}, Csize_t), s.ios, sz) != 0 &&
        throw(OutOfMemoryError())
end
```